# using switch-statement to check changing variable

Tags: java

I'm parsing a textfile where the first sign(s) of each line mean something different.

Right now i'm doing something like this:

```
while((line         = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {

    if(line.startsWith("O")) { .... }
    else if(line.startsWith("B")) { .... }
    else if(line.startsWith("30")) { .... }
    else if(line.startsWith("99")) { .... }
    else if(line.startsWith("00")) { .... }
```

I would rather want to accomplish this with a switch-statement but i'm not sure how i would go about doing that since i can only check for B which is one character long and 30 is two, otherwise i could just do line.subString(0,1).

I had something like this in mind but that doesn't work (obviously).

```
switch(line.startsWith(X)){
    case "B": //where B is replacing X
         break;
}
```

Comment: Java added `Switch...case`s with Strings in Java 7. What version of Java are you using? What error message are you getting when you try?

Comment: @AntonH java 8 i believe

Comment: @Progman No it doesn't. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) says: *"Returns: A String containing the contents of the line, **not** including any line-termination characters […]"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually as you noticed, your logic is more designed to work with a series of conditional statements (`if`) than a `switch` statement.
Making it work with a `switch` statement is possible but it will just make the logic more complex  as you will have to first extract the actual string by using `line.subString(0,1)` or `line.subString(0,2)` according to the content of the begining of the line.
Besides, in terms of code quality the two approaches are close enough.
So just keep your actual logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. Use Regular Expressions to separate the lines beginning with letters or two numbers. Then use a substring or the first char of the line to tell them apart.

```
if (line.matches("^[OB].*")) {
    switch(line.charAt(0)) {
        case 'O' :...
        case 'B' :...
        ...
    }
} else if (line.matches("^[0-9]{2}.*") {
    switch(line.substring(0,2)) {
        case "00":...
        case "30":...
        case "99":...
        ...
    }
}
```

This will separate your two first

Comment: +1 for somewhat of a solution but unfortunately not what i had in mind. I guess I have to scrap the idea.